# complete noob, How do I make a script to convert individual pages of a PDF as images AND save them in folders with the same name as the PDF?

Tags: image, pdf, ghostscript, file-conversion

For example, if I have book1.pdf and book2.pdf, I would like to create a script where the pages of the pdfs are converted to images and are saveed in their separate folders: book1 folder and book2 folder.

It's something this [program](http://www.a-pdf.com/image-extractor/index.htm) does but I do not want to pay 27 bucks just for this.

I'm a complete noob when it comes to coding. I installed Ghostscript and added a printer that runs ghostscript, so now I do have the option of opening a PDF (or any document), and print using the Ghostscript printer, and it outputs the resulting images to a folder.

This is the code for printer properties->ports->arguments for this program:

```
-sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -dJPEGQ=100 -o -dSAFER -sOutputFile="C:\IMAGEfiles\image%%03d.jpg" -
```

My goal now is to automate the system so that I can have a list of PDFs and convert their pages into images and sorted into folders based on the same name as the PDFs. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Ghostscript question really, this is a shell script programming problem.

Since you are using C: I'm assuming you are on Windows. I'm also going to assume you have created the folders in advance.

If you then open a command shell and do :

```
for %s in (*.pdf) do "c:\program files\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64c" -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -dJPEGQ=100 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=c:/%~ns/image%03d.jpg %s
```

That will find all the files with names of the form *.pdf, execute Ghostscript (you may have to alter the paths and executable name, it depends on the version you installed) and output the resulting JPG files to a folder whose names is the '*' part of the input filename.

Note that your original command line has both `-o` and `-sOutputFile`, you should modify it to remove one or the other. `-o` is supposed to be followed by the name of the output file and includes `-dBATCH` and `-dNOPAUSE` all wrapped up as one. Whereas -sOutputFile= just sets the output filename. Using both is a bad idea, if it works I'm surprised, and it certainly wouldn't surprise me if it stopped working at some point, or had unexpected side effects.